Need to Create an approval flow in power automate
I have created this power automate flow with the steps below, which runs fine, but when I add the same flow to escalate time out requests, though it runs fine and writes the outcome back in my data file, however it says test run fails and error is shown at apply to each and condition level.
[ I need a solution to remove the error message and have it run as green at each step]

Manually trigger a flow
List rows present in a table
Initialize variable
Apply to each - Condition if send email column in excel file from step 2 above is equal to YES then start step 5
Start and wait for approval
Apply to each – update a row with outcome and response comments
If start and wait for approval from the step 5 above times out then start another approval flow as escalation to the senior managers and complete the same steps from the previous flow.

i tried wrapping first flow in scope 1 and and 2nd flow in scope 2 and configured scope 2 to run after scope 1 is timed out. not working
